# springboot rest api: memory and cpu always in high level

Tags: web-services, spring-boot

I used spring boot to write Restful webservice
I do not use too many libraries and service only some api
For example one dependences I used

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp.wsdl</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
                <artifactId>webservices-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
                <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.bean</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

[image]

I don’t understand why deploy on server, when I check RAM and CPU then i saw them always high level: from 9 to 15% of RAM.

Please advice me how to improve performance and reduce RAM and CPU

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2015/12/10/spring-boot-memory-performance I would recommend you read that blog and point out what you believe to be high/nonperforming

Comment: in this way, you have no other way ?